# How to create a client proxy in WCF with the right command?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Different from the last command in doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-create-a-wcf-client, the program hints me to use 'svcutil.exe /language:cs /out:generatedProxy.cs /config:app.config http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service?wsdl' to generate client proxy code and the config file when I follow the tutorial exactly.

So I have two questions.

1. Does base address must start with 'http://'? Just like what is shown in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-host-and-run-a-basic-wcf-service. Can I use some other kind of base address if I don't use http binding?
2. If the answer to #1 is yes, what will the command be? It's better if you can give me an example.

Comment: added my answer if you have any further questions ill help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the base address must start with **http** or **https** because it needs to be hosted on a web server (like IIS). If you have done that you need to create a service reference to your project via: right click "Connected Services" --> add "Service reference" then type in your address choose your .svc file --> choose a name (e.g. ServiceRef) and click ok..

Then add your proxy to execute methods from the service like:

```
ServiceRef.ServiceRefClient proxy = new ServiceRef.ServiceRefClient();
bool testresult = proxy.TestConnection();
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I have another question.Is the base address only used for generating code and config file if I use absolute path in endpoint?

Comment: the base address points to your WCF, which contains all the methods and configurations for the web server. These will be added to your project by the service reference.

Comment: So if you change and/or add a method to your WCF you need to update your service reference in your project (right click on ServiceRef --> update service reference)